# Health for an enemy

Tags: python

I was coding a text adventure in python and I'm pretty new, but I know my way around. What I am having trouble with is my enemy(enemy1) is not losing health. Here's the code which will help you understand.

```
hp=100
punch=10
kick=20
kill=99999999
burger=10
soup=10
glass=999999999
nothing=100
enemy1=100

from time import sleep

print("What's Your name?")
usr=raw_input("> ")
print("Your starting health is 100"), usr
sleep(1)
print("You awake in your prison cell. You can go to the gym or outside.")
sleep(.5)
print("type gym or outside to go there")
cell=raw_input("> ")
if cell=="gym":
    print("You go to the gym. There are 2 guards here and 5 prisoners. You can lift weights, go outside, go to the cells or fight a prisoner")
    sleep(1)
    print("Type fight, weights, outside or cells")
    gym=raw_input("> ")
    if gym=="fight":
        print("You walk up to a prisoner and he stabs you.")
        sleep(2)
        print("Game Over"), usr
    if gym=="weights":
        print("You go and pick up some weights. You forget overwork yourself and die of a heart attack")
    if gym=="outside":
        print("You go outside to ")
if cell=="outside":
    print("You go outside. There are some people playing basketball and some people doing drugs. You can do drugs, play bball or fight someone")
    outside=raw_input("> ")
    if outside=="fight":
        print("You walk up to a guy")
        sleep(1)
        print("Hey, wanna fight?")
        sleep(1)
        print("Sure!")
        sleep(1)
        print("The stranger punches you.")
        sleep(1)
        print("Your health is now"), hp-punch
        while enemy1>0:
            print("You can kick or punch")
            fight1=raw_input("> ")
            if fight1=="punch":
                print("You punch that mothafucka")
                sleep(1)
                print("His health is"), enemy1-punch
            if fight1=="kick":
                print("You kick that mothafucka")
                sleep(1)
                print("His health is now"), enemy1-kick
            if fight1=="kill":
                print("You evicerate that mothafucka")
                sleep(1)
                print("His health is now"), enemy1-kill
        print("You win!")
```

Take not of when you go outside, you fight someone, his health goes back to one hundred. I figured out that its because I keep typing enemy1-x. I want to know how to get the enemy's health to lower and remember that it is lower, and when it hits zero that it breaks the while loop.

Comment: +1 for trying to code something really good (sorry SO). But not the best question for this site generally: you should try to minimize your code, i.e. provide as little code as possible that still demonstrates the difficulties you're facing.

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Your health is now"), hp-punch
print("His health is"), enemy1-punch
print("His health is now"), enemy1-kick
print("His health is now"), enemy1-kill
```

These lines don't actually change `hp` or `enemy1`. Use an *assignment statement* to change their values: `a -= b`, which is shorthand for `a = a - b`.

```
hp -= punch
print "Your health is now", hp

enemy1 -= punch
print "His health is", enemy1

enemy1 -= kick
print "His health is now", enemy1

enemy1 -= kill
print "His health is now", enemy1
```

Comment: I couldn't put it into a code block because I'm on a mobile and I'd have to type out each 8 spaces manually. Sorry!